# sql fiddle table does not exist

Tags: sql

I get error that thetable does not exist. What di i do wrong?

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/174184

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you did not create that table. Before running any query you have to build the schema.

i.e

```
create table contract(contract_id integer);
```

You can insert the data and perform your queries.

```
insert into contract values(4);
```

Otherwise it will give this error that table does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

you should create a table before executing a query.

```
CREATE TABLE contract (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     `name` VARCHAR(50) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
  )ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

see this [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2bfc57/1)